# How to start playing AVAudioPlayer while downloading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, avaudioplayer

I have a mp3 track at a URL http://mysite.com/MP3/track1.mp3.
Downloading it to a local path with NSURLConnection and NSDocumentDirectory.
I would like to start playing this track as soon as possible and not after it is completely downloaded. Is there a while to accomplish this? I have tried setting a "X" size limit, and once the download hits that number to start playing the track. But this only plays up to the point where it was initialized at the "X" size. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [self.inComingData appendData:data];
    //NSLog(@"inComingData: %d", [inComingData length]);

    CGFloat dataLen = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.inComingData length]] floatValue];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    appDelegate.path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"track.mp3"];
    [self.inComingData writeToFile:appDelegate.path atomically:YES];

//  NSInteger receivedLen = [self.inComingData length];
//  if ((receivedLen >= 100000) && (!checked)) {
//      //[appDelegate initAndPlay];
//      [appDelegate playTrack];
//      checked = TRUE;
//  }
    [appDelegate initPlayer];

}
```

Comment: If you want the data length as a float for some reason (can't see why since it will always be a whole number), what you're doing now is really inefficient. You can convert an integer value to a floating point in C (although make sure you're using the right size float so you don't lose too much). So you can just do: double dataLen = (double)[self.inComingData length];

Comment: Hey Jason, thanks for the reply. The float is for my progress bar. Thanks for the suggestion. But do you have any suggestions on how to play my AVAudioPlayer before the data is completely download and initialized?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using AVFoundation, you should probably look into using CoreAudio or AudioToolbox.

Matt Gallagher has a good tutorial for this exact situation, using AudioToolbox:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

Comment: Yea, I have read some of Matt's code before. But it is rather complex. I was trying to write my own code instead of using his. As for CoreAudio, I will have to try that out. Don't know much about it.

Comment: Well, AVAudioPlayer is pretty high level and doesn't give you a lot of options. I would say use AudioToolbox, since that's what I use in my app for playing files while downloading them.

Comment: Any real examples on how to play files while downloading them?