# Is there a way to start playing an MP3 file while downloading it in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, download, mp3, playback

Is there a way to start playing an MP3 file while downloading it in iOS? I saw this question

[How to start playing AVAudioPlayer while downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248260/how-to-start-playing-avaudioplayer-while-downloading)

Is AudioToolbox or CoreAudio the only way to do that?

Edit - I found this link

http://www.kyleshank.com/avplayer-can-play-a-file-as-its-being-written-to.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioFileStream, AudioQueue is the way to go. Implemented it the hard way. The link below helped me out :)

[lastFM source](https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question you already put a link to,

> AVAudioPlayer is pretty high level and
>   doesn't give you a lot of options

I think that you'll have to use AudioToolbox

Answer (score 0):

Use OPenAL for your purpose. Here is one wrapper for you http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/openal-sound-manager-class-updated/

Or you can use AudioToolbox as Alaa Nassef suggested.